# Fastest way to select record with time closest to the given

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a set of records, each having a `DateTime` field. Each record has time higher or equal to the previous record.

I need a fast query which will find a record with time closest to the provided time item.

A way of doing what I want would be using following queue:

```
select * from `mytable` order by abs(`time`-@mytime) asc limit 0,1;
```

But that takes quite some time to run.

Is there a better way to write this query?

***UPDATE***
The here is table's creation statement:

```
                    CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS `mydatabase`.`mytable` (
                      `id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      `itemid` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                      `time` DATETIME NOT NULL,
                      `closeTime` DATETIME,
                      `direction` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                      `price` DECIMAL(65,30) NOT NULL,
                      `volume` DECIMAL(65,30) NOT NULL,
                      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
                    )
                    ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: ok, I've updated the question adding table schema

Comment: Thanks for the progress report